# What is IDC connector pitch on a USBAsp?

Tags: arduino, avr, atmega, programmer, usbasp

I am planning to use a [USBASP programmer](https://protostack.com.au/shop/accessories/usbasp-avr-programmer/) to program one of my boards, and I want to use a fitting receptacle on my board. I fail to find the exact pitch that the USBAsp's IDC connector has (as I understand there are 2mm and 2.54mm pitches). Does anyone have any info?

Comment: AVR interfaces are almost always 2.54mm pitch. ARM tends to be 2mm nowdays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://github.com/ExploreEmbedded/AVR-USBasp-Programmer_V0.1) repository containing some design files and although the board is different from the one I'm gonna use, I'm assuming they do follow the same standard. The pitch on this one is 2.54mm. Feel free to correct me, but until then, I'll leave this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The ones in the picture are standard 2.54 mm pitch.

There are many more pitches than 2 and 2.54 mm. For example have a look at the pitch selector in Mouser: https://www.mouser.co.uk/Connectors/Headers-Wire-Housings/_/N-ay0lo